# Python Switching Active Cameras

Tags: python, windows, webcam

Here is the objective I wish to achieve: I would like to connect multiple web cameras to a single Windows machine and take snapshots from one of them at different instances (so one camera must active at one point of time, while another must be active at another). From what I have tried, an user has to go to the control panel and set which camera should be active at a given moment to use it. Is there a way to achieve this objective via python? (If there is a way to keep all cameras active at once, how should I specify which camera should take a snapshot?

Comment: show some code, show us what have you tried?

Comment: I was looking for a suggestion of what tools I could use to automate the procedure of switching cameras in the control panel, and also ways to address different cameras of all of them can be left activated to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have investigated a couple options since then. One of the tools that I could utilize is devcon, through which usb cameras could be disabled/enabled to take snapshots. Another (simpler) option is to use a function in python opencv - cv2.VideoCapture(i) will automatically allow the program to iterate through different camera devices connected to the computer via usb.